# ajax wordpress contact form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

**UPDATE:**

```
<form method="post" id="formApply"  action="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/inc/sendContact.php" name="applyForm">
    <div id="col1">
        <fieldset class="col-1">
            <div class="white info-line">Want to know more? Drop us a line and we'll get right back to you.</div>
            <label class="white text-label name" for="fname">Name:</label><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" tabindex="1" />
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <label class="white text-label email" for="email">Email:</label><input type="email" class="lower" name="email" id="email"  tabindex="2"/>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <label class="white text-label phone" for="phone">Phone:</label><input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" tabindex="3" maxlength="10"/>
            <div class="white text-label checker-title" id="checkererror">I am interested in:</div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2-1" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" name="checker[]" value="Office Space" /><label for="checkbox-2-1"></label><div class="white text-label checker">Office Space</div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2-2" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" name="checker[]" value="Designated Workspace" /><label for="checkbox-2-2"></label><div class="white text-label checker">Designated Workspace</div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2-3" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" name="checker[]" value="Shared Space" /><label for="checkbox-2-3"></label><div class="white text-label checker">Shared Space</div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
        <fieldset class="col-2">
            <label class="white text-label note-label" for="notes">Notes:</label><br/>
            <textarea name="notes" id="notes" rows="10" cols="30" class="requiredField" tabindex="4"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" class="submitted" value="true" /><button id="submit" type="submit">Submit Application</button>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
```

So i changed the form to a php on action - the email sends now fine - but it takes the user to the blank sendContact.php.

Is there a way of redirecting them back to the site? or doing this via ajax?

i tried a few ways in ajax and it wasnt sending the email

Thanks!

**PHP:**

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';


$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['fname']));
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$phone = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone']));
$notes  = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['notes']));
$checkbox = $_POST['checker'];


$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->setFrom(array('From_Email' => 'My Website'))
  ->setSubject('[My_Subject from '.$name.']')
  ->setTo(array('My_Email'))
  ->setBody(
'<html>'.
'<head></head>'.
'<body>'.
'<strong>Name:</strong><br />'.
$title.' '.$name.'<br /><br />'.
'<strong>Email Address:</strong><br />'.
$email.'<br /><br />'.
'<strong>Phone Number:</strong><br />'.
$phone.'<br /><br />'.
'<strong>Interested in:</strong><br />'.
implode('<br />', $checkbox).'<br /><br />'.
'<strong>Message:</strong><br />'.
$notes.'<br /><br />'.
'</body>'.
'</html>',
'text/html' );
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: paste your javascript ajax code please

Comment: Also button type is submit and you need to make it simple button and then do the submit using javascript ajax way.

Comment: i updated with the javascript

Comment: @Mark there is a JS error on the page that says "TypeError: $ is not a function", so please change $ to jQuery like jQuery("form#applywrap").submit and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to implement Ajax in WordPress is to use admin-ajax.php

In your functions.php of your template add following code

```
function MyAjaxCallBack()
{
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        $$key = $value;
    //Email script will go here!
    die();
}

// creating Ajax call for WordPress  
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_MyAjaxCallBack', 'MyAjaxCallBack');
add_action('wp_ajax_MyAjaxCallBack', 'MyAjaxCallBack');
```

Ajax script (Add it to header.php or footer.php):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    jQuery("#PleasePushMe").click(function(){ 
        jQuery.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',  
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>',  
            data: {  
                action: 'MyAjaxCallBack',
                MyParam: 'MyParamValue'
            },  
            success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){  
                alert(data);  
            },  
            error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){  
                alert(errorThrown);  
            }  
        });  
    });  
});
```

Comment: nothing is happening when i put require( get_template_directory() . '/inc/sendContact.php' ) inside of the die() function.

Comment: @Mark form action is optional but you can add action like action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>?action=MyAjaxCallBack"

Comment: Thanks man - just i'm not sure how to implement the script into the die() function - should i include the sendContact.php file in it?

Comment: @Mark I've updated my answer, email script will not go inside die()

Answer (score 0):

Use `id` selector for form.

**Replace**

```
var data = $(".applywrap > form").serialize();
```

**With**

```
var data = $("#applywrap > form").serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

### You need to add a [submit handler](https://api.jquery.com/submit/):

```
$(function(){

    $(".applywrap > form").on("submit", function(){
        // here you should probably validate your form fields...

        $.ajax({
            type : this.method,
            url  : this.action, // HTML <form> "action" attribute
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false
        })
        .done(console.log)
        .fail(console.warn)

        return false; // so the form won't refresh the page
    });

});
```

Comment: i forgot - i added a submit handler - i think its doing its thing its the ajax to php that im having a hard time with. I'll update my post with the php code